# admin firebase auth and node js

Tags: node.js, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I'm working on android app and I use node js back end and Firebase platform for my app, I manage users with firebase-auth, and the problem is when I register a new user to firebase-auth using node js I see this error.
This is the source code.

```
    function registerUser(socket,io){
​// retrieve data from android app 
  socket.on('userData',(data)=>{
    console.log(data.email);
    console.log(data.userName);
    console.log(data.password);
​
​// register new user using data.
    admin.auth().createUser({
      email: data.email,
      password: data.password,
      displayName: data.userName,
    })
      .then(function(userRecord) {
        // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
        console.log("Successfully created new user:", userRecord.uid);
        const db = admin.database();
        const ref = db.ref('users/');
        const userid = ref.child(encodeEmail(data.email));
        userid.set({
          username: data.userName,
          email: data.email,
          password:data.password
        }).then((error)=>{
          console.log('successfully write in database real time ');
        });
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error creating new user:", error);
      });
});
}
```

and this is the error:

```
Error creating new user: { Error: www.googleapis.com network timeout. Please try again.
    at FirebaseAppError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:39:28)
    at new FirebaseAppError (/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:84:23)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (friend-chat-server/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/api-request.js:121:51)
    at emitNone (events.js:105:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:207:7)
    at TLSSocket.Socket._onTimeout (net.js:398:8)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:469:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:304:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:264:5)
  errorInfo: 
   { code: 'app/network-timeout',
     message: 'www.googleapis.com network timeout. Please try again.' } }
```

firebase added to node js successfully everything good but i don't know how to fix this . help please!

Comment: How do you initialize the admin SDK?